# Component with configurable function/api calls

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm asking myself if our current implementation is the "best" way or if any other approach would be better.

Given a search component which displays its result in a dropdown. We need this component for many usecases like searching for locations or for persons. Therefore we need to do **different API requests**.

Our **current approach** is to use a `AbstractSearchInput.vue` component which has an "abstract" method `executeSearch()` which is overwritten in our concrete components `LocationSearchInput.vue`or `PersonSearchInput.vue`.

```js
<template>
  <input @input="performSearch"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "AbstractSearchInput",
  data() {
    return {
      query: "",
      result: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async executeSearch(query) {
      // concrete components extending this abstract component need to implement this method
      throw new Error("No implementation");
    },
    async performSearch() {
      this.result = await this.executeSearch(query);
    },
    // more stuff
  },
};
</script>
```

```js
<script>
import { queryPersons } from "../personsApi";

export default {
  name: "PersonsSearchInput",
  extends: AbstractSearchInput,
  methods: {
    async executeSearch(query) {
      const persons = await queryPersons(query);
      return persons;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

personsApi.js

```js
async function queryPersons() {
  const response = await fetch(url); // shortened

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Foo");

  return response.json();
}
```

This inheritance approach is working. However, its **drawback** is that we need a concrete component for each new usecase. Imagine we need to search for fruits, logos or something else...

At the beginning I thought there would be a way to **make this component configurable**. I imagined that there would be just one search component that you could configure externally for what to search for. Like passing the API request to the component via a prop. However passing functions as props is an anti-pattern. Are there any other considerations which may be produce less boilerplate code?

Thanks so far :slight_smile:

Comment: Are you using vue 3?

Comment: Yea using vue3.

Comment: I think it's good to use a composable function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a composable function called `useSearch` which takes the `url` as parameter and return the `result` :

```js
import  {ref} from 'vue'

export default function useSearch(cb){

  const result=ref([]);
  async function performSearch() {
      result.value = await cb();
    }

  return { performSearch, result }
}
```

In a component :

```html
<script>
import {ref} from 'vue'
import useSearch from './useSearch'
import { queryPersons } from "../personsApi";

export default {
  name: "PersonsSearchInput",
  setup(){
    
    const { performSearch, result:persons }= useSearch(queryPersons)
  
  return { performSearch, persons }
}

};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. However, this approach does not use the function for the api request `queryPersons`. I want to call functions ot of different modules (`personsApi.js`, `locationApi.js`, ...).  How could i override my implementation for `executeSearch`? Do i need to use a callback?

Comment: Please share the code of `queryPersons`

Comment: I extended my original post.

Comment: @Theiaz please check my edited answer

Comment: Okay, saying i want to keep the api code inside a module (cause its used from somewhere else), this approach would not work. Hence, I need to pass the `queryPersons`-Function as a callback `executeSearch(callback) { callback() }`.

Comment: Yes could do that by passing the callback to the composable function

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try to implement it and mark your answer as accepted answer.